# Creating and structuring the index page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, user-interface

I have a test website [www.lemonbrush.com](http://lemonbrush.com) is has the two menu items "`Home`" and "`About`".

When we click on the "`About`" menu, the About page is loaded dynamical, which is great, but when I type the About page's url directly `http://www.lemonbrush.com/about.html` into the address bar, my whole plan goes for six.

I need some guidance in  how shall I structure and load the pages so that the whole header and navigation are included even when we use the direct URL in the address bar.

My skills are HTML and Javascript.

Please see the following screen shots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: haven't done this by myself. but instead of changing the url to /about.html, i'd suggest to use the js location hash as starting point. something like mydomain.com#about and in your js, you get the hash onload to decide, which page to load...

Comment: @errand, thanks for the reply,   can you please lead me to an example so I can understand what you mean?

Comment: as i already told, haven't tried it yet, but see see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp for explanation of the hash. as i understand it, you could always call index.html but add the subpage via location hash, like index.html#about and in your js, you read the location hash to decide, which page to load.

Comment: http://ajaxpatterns.org/Unique_URLs - i guess, this will help, too ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you're clicking the menu item you are updating the page with the data, but when you are going to the link directly you are just getting the data. one way around this is to have common elements for the page, ie. navigation menus, In a javascript file and then use a script tag with a link where you want it on the page.

Answer (score 0):

so, since i thought it would be nice for my project, to have a usable browser history and bookmarkable subpages, i yesterday tried the approach from my comments of the OP.

step 1: change the anchors in your navigation bar to something like that:

```
<a href="#index">home</a>
<a href="#about">about</a>
```

needles to say, that they don't need to be inside the same parent element. those links could be anywhere.

step 2: remove the on click handler from your script, that reacts on the navigation bar clicks!

step 3: create a function, to listen to the onhashchange event. (this has to be done once, on the main html page)

```
//create a function for the onhashchange event
window.onhashchange = function()
{
    //check if a location hash is used
    if(window.location.hash != null) 
    { 
        //store current location hash in a variable
        requestedPage = location.hash;
        //remove the '#' from the location hash value
        requestedPage = requestedPage.replace('#','');

        //load content from subpage into your content frame
        $('#contentFrame').load('./' + requestedPage + '.html', function( response, status, xhr ) 
        {
            //catch 'file not found' errors and load start page
            if ( status == "error" ) {
                $('#mainPanel').load('./start.html');
            }
        });
};
```

for your page, you have of course to adapt, use the correct selectors and the correct file names.

you then would call your page via www.mydomain.com, and every subdomain via www.mydomain.com/#subPage