# How to link to a specific jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery menu. For example if I click on "Contacts" it points to #contacts
and a popup is displayed via jquery. Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
$('#contacts').on('click', function ( e ) {
    $.fn.custombox( this, {
    effect: 'fall'
});
    e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

I am trying to link the contacts page to other people but www.mysite.com/#contacts shows the homepage.
How I manage to accomplish my goal (to distribute a simple direct link to the "internal page")?

EDIT
based on errand answer I found my solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
switch (location.hash) {
case '#centr':
          $.fn.custombox( document.getElementById('centr'), {
    effect: 'fall'
});
    break;
case '#sxalto':
    $.fn.custombox( document.getElementById('sxalto'), {
    effect: 'fall'
});
    break;
case '#dxalto':
    $.fn.custombox( document.getElementById('dxalto'), {
    effect: 'fall'
});
    break;
case '#sxbasso':
    $.fn.custombox( document.getElementById('sxbasso'), {
    effect: 'fall'
});
    break;
case '#dxbasso':
    $.fn.custombox( document.getElementById('dxbasso'), {
    effect: 'fall'
});
    break;
case '#basso':
    $.fn.custombox( document.getElementById('basso'), {
    effect: 'fall'
});
    break;
case '#sottosotto':
    $.fn.custombox( document.getElementById('sottosotto'), {
    effect: 'fall'
});
    break;
} 
});
```

Comment: you are using angular or knockout else check this https://github.com/aaronblohowiak/routes.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when i got you right, you append a location hash to your url and want, that people are able to directly get to the subpage, instead of the main page.
i solved it that way:

on my index.html i got the following js code

```
$(window).load(function() {
    if(location.hash)
    {
        linkedHash = location.hash //read the location hash variable
        // and here comes your personal load code, based on the appended location hash
    }
```

deeper explanation can be found in my answer here:
[Creating and structuring the index page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26841754/creating-and-structuring-the-index-page/26881922#26881922)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
$('#contacts').on('click', function () {
    window.location.href= "www.google.com";//or any other page
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use jQuery Mobile and use something like this

```
<body> 

<!-- Start of first page -->
<div data-role="page" id="foo">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Foo</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>I'm first in the source order so I'm shown as the page.</p>      
        <p>View internal page called <a href="#bar">bar</a></p> 
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /header -->
</div><!-- /page -->


<!-- Start of second page -->
<div data-role="page" id="bar">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Bar</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>I'm first in the source order so I'm shown as the page.</p>      
        <p><a href="#foo">Back to foo</a></p>   
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /header -->
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want an initial visit to `www.mysite.com/#contacts` to open the Contacts popup. This might do it:

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    var $target;
    if(window.location.hash) {
        $target = $(window.location.hash);
        if($target.length) {
            $target.trigger("click");
        }
    }
});
```

It looks to see if there is an element on the page with an ID matching the hash. If there is, it triggers the click event on it, which will call your code to present the popup.